# css selector in beautiful soup not finding a tag

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

There are plenty of similar questions to this, but none have answered my question. I am trying to use a CSS selector to find a tag in beautiful soup.

[The specific section of html I am trying to scrape, as the full html is quite large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edaRt.png)

The url I am scraping from is in my code.

here is some test code that hopefully shows my problem:

```
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201510310MEM.html"
response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read().decode()

# proves the element I am selecting exists in the html
print(html.find("table class=\"suppress_all stats_table\" id=\"four_factors\" data-cols-to-freeze=\",1\"")) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# this line prints a similar piece of data to the one I want, but not correct
print(soup.select('tbody > tr > td[data-stat="off_rtg"]')[0].get_text())

# when I try being more specific, it prints an empty list
print(soup.select('table[id="four_factors"] tbody > tr > td[data-stat="off_rtg"]'))
```

Output:

```
78720
98
[]
```

As my code illustrates, an element that can be found using python's String.find() method is for some reason invisible to BeautifulSoup.  I've tried using the BeautifulSoup.find() and .findAll() instead of a css selector with the same results. I've tried using the lxml parser with the same results.

Comment: Please provide a link to the html you're scraping (for instance using pastebin) rather than an image, it makes testing much easier :)

Comment: I can try that, but if you need the full html can't you just go to the link in the code, right click, and choose inspect? @Seon

Comment: My bad, I read through quite quickly and missed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the table is within HTML comments (`<!--...-->`).

You can extract the table checking if the tags are of the type [`Comment`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201510310MEM.html"
response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read().decode()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda tag: isinstance(tag, Comment))
comment_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(comments), "html.parser")

print(
    comment_soup.select_one(
        'table[id="four_factors"] tbody > tr > td[data-stat="off_rtg"]'
    ).text
)
```

Output:

```
102.5
```

Comment: This worked! But I have a few questions: 1. I found a version of the table within comments in the page's html, but I also found a version outside of any comments. You can see in the picture in my post the version outside of any comments. If it was within comments, the highlighting would be green, right? 2. If the table is inside of comments, why does it show up on the web page?

Comment: the page is rendered by js. So the source html it comes in as comments, then javascript runs to creat the table you see on the site.